# MVC4 Application Design/Solution Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

I am going to build a new MVC4 web based application, so i would need to create new solution and different kind of projects. So my question what type of projects i would need in my solutions.

My requirement is as following-

1. We have different travel agents working with us each having its unique name. May be 4-5 for now. The plan is to create 4-5 different URLs and handle it over to those travel agents.

Here is a sample User Story

1. User (for e.g travel agent id 1) should be able to come to URL mywebsite/agent/1 and he sees all the available tickets related to that agent which will coming from external web service and is not under my control.
2. He selects the products and click buy which again calls up some web service goes to their service and comes back with confirmation number.

This is pretty much it for the application.

So my question is in terms of what all projects should i create for such application.

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you will get a much warmer response to it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. SO is considered to be more of a syntax / direct Q & A computing question forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you get a copy of either [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, Third Edition](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430234040/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d7_i7?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0Z27DGCRYXHGXZR4M1Z1&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375923922&pf_rd_i=915398) or [Pro Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430242361/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d7_i1?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0Z27DGCRYXHGXZR4M1Z1&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375923922&pf_rd_i=915398). Either way, i usually do a blank solution and then add 3 projects like `Something.WebUI`, `Something.Domain`, `Something.UnitTests (Only if you want to write tests, highly recommended)`.

Another option is you can head to Pluralsight and watch a video by [Scott Allen](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building)